# Requiring a super fast postgres SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query I am trying to solve for Postgresql

I first generate a series of dates as such:

```
with t as(
SELECT 
    uuid_generate_v4() as generated_id,
    date_trunc('day', dd):: date as generated_date,
    '75e46430-2f19-c9fc-5c8a-1aeb423a7c84'::uuid as account_id
FROM generate_series
        ( '2019-04-01'::timestamp 
        , '2019-05-01'::timestamp
        , '1 day'::interval) dd
)
```

I then have another table [Transactions] which is like follows:

```
account_id | order_date | debit_amount | credit_amount
```

The transactions table can have thousands of entries for a given account per day.  Each transaction will either be a debit or a credit, i.e. if it is a credit there will be a value in the credit column and the debit column will be null for a particular transaction.

I am trying to devise a superfast query that gives me the result of:

```
generated_id | account_id | order_date | sum(total_of debits_for_order_date) | sumtotal_of_credits_for_order_date)
```

Where:

```
order_date = generated_date 
t.account_id = transations.account_id
```

If the debits or credits are null for a particular date I still need to return an empty row.

e.g.

```
generated_id  |  account_id  |  generated_date |  debit  |  credit
fjsda-klf...     75e46430...      2019-01-01      1.50      null
gassd-fsd...     75e46430...      2019-01-02      null      null
```

Comment: where is your generated_date?

Comment: The `account_id` values in the CTE do not match the expected result. Are you sure it's the same column?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ I have just updated.  The result should show the generated_date not the order_date.  But the order date must match the generated_date in the query.

Comment: @TheImpaler  I have edited the post to reflect.  Cheers

Comment: You are aware that a query that will read and process a whole large table will never be "super fast", right? I guess it depends on your definition of "super fast".

Comment: Note that `uuid_generate_v4()` is substantially slower than `gen_random_uuid()` from the [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.9) extension

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I guess I was just trying to see what the fastest method would be.    Is sitting at about 1.3 seconds with the query from JuSun below so I suppose that will suffice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't see a speed difference although it is only generating about 30 lines worth of UUID (for the month)

Comment: You can try `explain analyze select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1,1e5)` and `explain analyze select gen_random_uuid() from generate_series(1,1e5)`. The first one takes 36 **seconds** on my laptop, the second one 60 **milli**seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query.

```
with t as(
SELECT 
    uuid_generate_v4() as generated_id,
    date_trunc('day', dd):: date as generated_date,
    '75e46430-2f19-c9fc-5c8a-1aeb423a7c84'::uuid as account_id
FROM generate_series
        ( '2019-04-01'::timestamp 
        , '2019-05-01'::timestamp
        , '1 day'::interval) dd
), tdata as (
  select a.account_id, a.order_date, sum(debit_amount) as debit, sum(credit_amount) as credit
from transations a
where exists (
  select 1 from t where t.generated_date = a.order_date and t.account_id = a.account_id
)
select t.generated_id, t.account_id, t.generated_date, m.debit, m.credit
from t left join tdata m on (t.generated_date = m.order_date and t.account_id = m.account_id)
```